# Displays in order the most common items in a list with the index name

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like to use something like the frequency vector and also display the most common indexes in a list and how many times they meet and make a top of it
I have something like this now but I don't know how I could count on it

```
from collections import Counter
class AttributesCount:
  @staticmethod
  def count():
    object = [
        {"width":"32"},
        {"color":"red"},
        {"color:":"red"},
        {"color":"black"},
        {"color":"orange"},
        {"color":"red"}]
    for i in object:
        

print(AttributesCount.count())
```

I've seen all kinds of count functions, collections but I want exactly what I said above, to make a top
How can I do this?

```
from collections import Counter I tried with this but I is not correctly
```

Comment: it is no clear what do you want to count. please explain. add a valid data structure to the post

Comment: send example from what do you want?

Comment: To count how many times something appears there and at the end to make a ranking with the score (ie the number of occurrences and the key name + value) @user1740577

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition to use a `Counter` is correct.

Given a list of dictionaries with the variable name `attribute_list`, we first populate the `Counter`.

We can loop over the keys of each dictionary in the list and add 1 to each count, but we can be more succinct using `Counter`'s [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) method.

Then we can call `Counter`'s [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method to return a list of tuples in descending frequency:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> frequencies = Counter()
>>> for attribute in attribute_list:
...     frequencies.update(attribute.keys())
...
>>> frequencies
Counter({'width': 1, 'color': 4, 'color:': 1})
>>> frequencies.most_common()
[('color', 4), ('width', 1), ('color:', 1)]
```